# vim: vnew, but accepting a buffer instead of a filename?

Tags: vim

Currently, if I want to create a new window then load a buffer, I use `:vnew` `:buf foo.py`. Is there one command which will do both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a command for that:

```
:[N]sb[uffer] [N]                   :sb :sbuffer
        Split window and edit buffer [N] from the buffer list.  If [N]
        is not given, the current buffer is edited.  Respects the
        "useopen" setting of 'switchbuf' when splitting.  This will
        also edit a buffer that is not in the buffer list, without
        setting the 'buflisted' flag.
```

You may find these ones useful also:

```
:[N]sbn[ext] [N]                                    :sbn :sbnext
        Split window and go to [N]th next buffer in buffer list.
        Wraps around the end of the buffer list.  Uses 'switchbuf'

:[N]sbN[ext] [N]            :sbN :sbNext :sbp :sbprevious
:[N]sbp[revious] [N]
        Split window and go to [N]th previous buffer in buffer list.
        Wraps around the start of the buffer list.
        Uses 'switchbuf'.
```

The problem with both commands is that they will split horizontally. You can precede them with `:vert[ical]`, but that breaks your one command paradigm :-)

Anyway, `:vert sb foo.py` is not that much of typing, and if you really use it often, you might want to consider creating a map for it. Maybe something like:

```
cnoremap ,sb vert sb
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tell `:vnew` the path to the file:

```
:vnew foo.py
```

Edit:

As sidyll said, there is no built in command that splits the window vertically to edit a buffer, then I have created a new ex commands which does what you want:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=buffer -bang Vbuffer vnew | buf<bang> <args>
```

The `!` after `command` will replace an old `:Vbuffer` if it exists (you can remove that since I have added it for testing), `-nargs=1` means that the new command accepts 1 argument which is passed to the `:buf` command with `<args>`, `-complete=buffer` will suggest buffer names as you type <kbd>tab</kbd> for the argument name and `-bang` indicates that the new command accepts the `!` option which is also passed to the `:buf` command with `<bang>`.

Just add that line to your `~/.vimrc` and re-`:source` it. ;-)

Comment: As @jm666 says. I'm often working with files all over the filesystem, so I prefer using :buf because I only need to supply part of the name.

Comment: Upvoting, really nice. Creating a new command is a solution that didn't occur in my mind, and it's way better than a simple map in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I have spent a little time figuring out how to customize the command to make it almost identical to the former one and I thought it would be a shame not to share it. =)